# SAS Transpose Keeping Flags

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with multiple IDs as such:

```
ID  Flag1   Flag2   Flag3
1   1       0       0
1   0       0       1
1   0       1       0
2   1       0       0
2   0       1       0
3   etc etc
```

I would like to combine each ID into 1 line keeping the flags.

```
ID  Flag1   Flag2   Flag3
1   1       1       1
2   1       1       0
3   etc.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You should provide a minimal working example (a data step that helps us create your data) and show us what you've done so far. You need to do the basic research before simply asking us to solve a problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
proc means data=have;
class id;
var flag1 flag2 flag3;
output out=want sum=;
run;
```

Or `max` if you could have multiple instances of each flag.

Comment: Thank you. For whatever reason I was blanking. This will do.